# Python: Copy panda and replace specific column value in a single step

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How would I create a new data frame and replace the values *in a specific column* with a single statement?

Say I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

student_ids = ['abc123', 'def321', 'qwe098', 'rty135']
extra_junk  = ['whoa', 'hey', 'don\'t touch me', 'junk']
gpas        = ['3.1', 'junk', 'NaN', '2.75']
aa          = np.array([student_ids, extra_junk, gpas]).transpose()

df = pd.DataFrame(data= aa, columns=['student_id', 'extra_junk', 'gpa'])

>>> df
  student_id      extra_junk   gpa
0     abc123            whoa   3.1
1     def321             hey  junk
2     qwe098  don't touch me   NaN
3     rty135            junk  2.75
```

I can do it in two:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['gpa'] = df2['gpa'].replace('junk', 'NaN')

>>> df2
  student_id      extra_junk   gpa
0     abc123            whoa   3.1
1     def321             hey   NaN
2     qwe098  don't touch me   NaN
3     rty135            junk  2.75
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You want to combine (1) copying dataframe, and (2) replacing values in a series, into one command? *What is the specific reason why this is necessary?*

Comment: You will find several answers to this question. But, for the sake of other users, note the 2 liner is the *clearest answer* you will ever find. Don't 1-linise your code unless it adds something (clarity; performance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the nested dictionary syntax of [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df2 = df.replace({'gpa':{'junk':'NaN'}})
```

From the docs:

> Nested dictionaries, e.g., {‘a’: {‘b’: nan}}, are read as follows: look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it with nan.

Note that using `'NaN'` will replace it with a string. If you want it to be an actual `NaN`, use `np.nan`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assign` to create a copy and do the replace.

```
df2 = df.assign(gpa = df.gpa.replace('junk', 'NaN'))
df2
```

Output:

```
  student_id      extra_junk   gpa
0     abc123            whoa   3.1
1     def321             hey   NaN
2     qwe098  don't touch me   NaN
3     rty135            junk  2.75
```